# Excel: How to count the number of times a range of data contains two values in the same row

Tags: excel

I have a range of cells with rows of matches containing 3 teams each in B1:D80. 
Array of matches example:

5  2  8

4  7  9

9  2  3

...

There are 40 teams total that I listed vertically and horizontally.
Array of teams example

___9___4___3...

9

4

3
    ...

My goal is to count the number of times a row in the array of matches contains both the number on the left and top of the array of teams. So, in the first cell of the array of teams, 9 and 9 would obviously be just counting the number of times 9 shows up. Then go one cell to the right and you have 9 on the left and 4 on the top. In this case I need to count the number of times the array of matches contains both 9 and 4 in the same row. Go over 1 more and I would count the number of times 9 and 3 show up in the same row. If I could do this row by row I would, but it is 80 rows so that is not what I want to do.

I have tried =countif(B1:D80,AND(I2,K1)) and =countif(B1:D80,{"I2","K1"}), but they either come out with 0 or an error.

Any help on doing this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest solution i could think of is using `Sumproducts`.

Let your array of matches be in `B1:D5` (for example)

in the first cell corresponding to 9 and 9 input

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$5=$G2)*($C$1:$C$5=H$1))+SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$5=$G2)*($D$1:$D$5=H$1))+SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$C$5=$G2)*($D$1:$D$5=H$1)) + SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$5=H$1)*($C$1:$C$5=$G2))+SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$5=H$1)*($D$1:$D$5=$G2))+SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$C$5=H$1)*($D$1:$D$5=$G2))
```

the formula has six parts. each part checks

if the left number occurs in first column and(*) the top number occurs in the 2nd column

or(+)

if the left number occurs in first column and(*) the top number occurs in the 3rd column

or(+)

if the left number occurs in 2nd column and(*) the top number occurs in the 3rd column

or(+)

if the top number occurs in first column and(*) the left number occurs in the 2nd column

or(+)

if the top number occurs in first column and(*) the left number occurs in the 3rd column

or(+)

if the top number occurs in 2nd column and(*) the left number occurs in the 3rd column

[image: Solution Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For 3 columns you can use this approach

`=SUMPRODUCT((($B$1:$B$80=K$1)+($C$1:$C$80=K$1)+($D$1:$D$80=K$1)>0)*(($B$1:$B$80=$I2)+($C$1:$C$80=$I2)+($D$1:$D$80=$I2)>0))`

I'm assuming that if `I2` = `K1` you just want a count of rows that contain that value

You can get the same results using `MMULT` or `FREQUENCY` functions in array formulas which can more easily be extended to a range with many columns, i.e.

`=SUM((MMULT(($B$1:$D$80=K$1)+0,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B$1:$D$80)^1))>0)*(MMULT(($B$1:$D$80=$I2)+0,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B$1:$D$80)^1))>0))`

or

`=SUM(IF((FREQUENCY(IF($B$1:$D$80=K$1,ROW($B$1:$D$80)),ROW($B$1:$D$80))>0)*(FREQUENCY(IF($B$1:$D$80=$I2,ROW($B$1:$D$80)),ROW($B$1:$D$80))>0),1))`

both confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>